# The "Profile Picture" section just disappeared from my User Profile

Tags: profiles, avatar

The *"Profile Picture"* section just disappeared from my User Profile.

How do I get it back?

Thanks.

Comment: Nothing in WordPress structure should change without interaction of an admin/user. Did you change the theme? Activate/deactivate a plugin?

Answer (score 1):

The profile picture is shown in your profile only if you have the `Show Avatar` option enabled in the discussion settings.

Head over to `Settings > Discussions` and under `Avatars` section, enable the `Show Avatars` checkbox and save the changes.

Now you can see that your profile picture is back in your profile.